# Reserve IP based on DHCP Option 61 insted of MAC Address

Tags: powershell, dhcp, dhcp-server, windows-server-2022, dhcp-option

a DHCP client is sending a discovery packet with option 61. Now the Windows server 2019 /2022 needs to respond with the offer based on the DHCP reservation, reservation is registered based on option 61 value. However Serve is not generating offers based on my reservation.

- I won't have mac address, in this scenario.

This is due to the reservation is not configured correctly. I use win server 2022.

DHCP Discovery Packet
[DHCP Discovery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFzi3.png)

Add reservation dialog [DHCP Reservation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2i7W.png)

The string value is not accepted, I get the below error
[DHCP Reservation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNS1D.png)

Either Powershell code did not make any difference

`Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ScopeId $Scope.ScopeId -IPAddress $IPAddress -ClientId $ClientIdWithPrefix -Type Dhcp`

Expecting help, on How to configure DHCP reservation based on IP address v4 and Option 61.
Thanks in advance.